# Facebook Authentication on android device causes failure of application (Titanium android)

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, nullpointerexception, titanium-mobile

In my application I am using facebook authentication.My code looks like

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    layout:'vertical'
});win1.open();

Titanium.Facebook.appid = "appid";
Titanium.Facebook.permissions = ['abc'];

var facebook_button = Ti.UI.createButton(
{
    height:50,
    width:200
});win1.add(facebook_button);
facebook_button.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    Titanium.Facebook.authorize();  
});
var facebook = Titanium.Facebook.createLoginButton({
    style:'wide',
    bottom:80
});
win1.add(facebook);
Titanium.Facebook.addEventListener('login', connect_facebook);

function connect_facebook()
{
    alert('inside');
    Titanium.Facebook.logout();
}
```

Now problem occur when I click on facebook_button. When I install application on android device(version 2.2) I click on facebook_button it causes forced close of application. after forced close If I again start application and use same functionality it's working fine.My log records gives following error **java.lang.NullPointerException**. 
if I use titanium facebook button i.e. **Ti.Facebook.createLoginButton** it's not giving any error even on first use also. But I want to use my own customize log-in button.
I want to remove this null pointer exception. I am using android sdk 2.0.1. and tested on android device 2.2.On simulator application running without any error.Is there any way to solve this problem? need help.. thank you..

Comment: Why are you using both buttons (facebook_button and facebook)in the code?

Comment: Hi muhammad thank you for quick reply. I am using both buttons just for testing. If I use only own created button i.e. facebook_button then also it's giving same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in connecting to Facebook from Titanium, but installed one of their new example apps two days ago: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Example+Applications#ExampleApplications-ARti

This connects to FB, do not know in what way. You can download example code from GitHub, maybe you find it useful.

Besides, in my experience the older Android SDK versions you are using have some issues. I have better experiences using 2.3 and newer. Recently compiled an app with SDK 4.x and have it running on a device with 2.2, so no problems with backward compatibility. Maybe it helps to upgrade your SDKs.